# Spring WS Client update variable outside of callback

Tags: java, spring, soap, callback, spring-ws

I'm extracting the HTTP response from WebServiceMessageCallback, but when I try to update a variable outside of the callback, I get: Cannot refer to a non-final variable rawResponse inside an inner class defined in a different method"

```
String rawResponse=null;
try { 
    this.webserviceTemplate.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult(source,
        new WebServiceMessageCallback() {
                @Override
                public void doWithMessage(WebServiceMessage message)
                        throws IOException, TransformerException {
                    TransportContext context = TransportContextHolder.getTransportContext();
                    CommonsHttpConnection  connection = (CommonsHttpConnection  )context.getConnection();
                    context.getConnection();
                    rawResponse = connection.getPostMethod().getResponseBodyAsString();*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You really should do it using `final` variable. The `AtomicReference` is for you:

```
final AtimicReference<String> rawResponse = new AtimicReference<String>();
try { 
    this.webserviceTemplate.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult(source,
        new WebServiceMessageCallback() {
                @Override
                public void doWithMessage(WebServiceMessage message)
                        throws IOException, TransformerException {
...
                    rawResponse.set(connection.getPostMethod().getResponseBodyAsString());
```